# Laggy animation on changing height of grid

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a Navigation Drawer by changing the width of Grid.

XAML :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="900" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="500"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="OnFlick"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!-- left panel... keep width as 0 when app starts-->
        <Grid Name="leftpanel" Width="400">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image 
                    Source="/Images/dp.png" 
                    Margin="0,40" 
                    x:Name="myimage" 
                    Tap="myimage_Tap" 
                    Height="120" 
                    Width="120" 
                    Stretch="Fill" 
                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                    <Image.Clip>
                        <EllipseGeometry
                                Center="60,60"
                                RadiusX="60"
                                RadiusY="60" />
                    </Image.Clip>
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform"/>
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
                <TextBlock
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="name"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,-20,0,0"
                    FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,5">
                    <Image Source="/Images/loc.png"
                           Height="30"
                           Width="30"/>

                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="20,30,0,0">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="text"
                        FontSize="35"
                        Margin="20,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="20,20,0,0"
                    Name="x">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="text"
                        FontSize="35"
                        Margin="20,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="20,20,0,0">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="Moments"
                        FontSize="35"
                        Margin="20,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="20,20,0,0">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="text"
                        FontSize="35"
                        Margin="20,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="20,20,0,0">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="x"
                        FontSize="35"
                        Margin="20,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="20,20,0,0">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock
                    Foreground="White"
                    Text="text"
                        FontSize="35"
                        Margin="20,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Line X1="0" X2="1"
                    Margin="0,20,0,0"
                    Stroke="White"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    Stretch="Fill"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <StackPanel
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Height="80">
                    <Button 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        Width="199"
                        Height="80">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image 
                                Source="/Images/x.png"
                                Height="35"
                                Width="35"/>
                            <TextBlock 
                                Text="text"
                                Margin="10,0"
                                FontSize="35"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Line X1="0"  Y2="100"

                    Stroke="White"
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    Stretch="Fill"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        Width="199"
                        Height="80">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image 
                                Source="/Images/x.png"
                                Height="35"
                                Width="35"/>
                            <TextBlock 
                                Text="text"
                                Margin="10,0"
                                FontSize="35"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Width="500" x:Name="mainpanel" Background="Black">
        </Grid>


    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind :

```
private void OnFlick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)
        {

            // User flicked towards left ==== show main panel
            if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
            {
                if (leftpanel.Width > 0)    
                {

                    Slideright(leftpanel);

                }
            }

            // User flicked towards right  ===== show left panel
            if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
            {
                if (leftpanel.Width < 400)
                {
                    Slideleft(leftpanel);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Slideleft(Grid leftpanel)
    {
        DoubleAnimation tAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        tAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
        tAnimation.From = 0;
        tAnimation.To = 400;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(tAnimation, leftpanel);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tAnimation, new PropertyPath(Grid.WidthProperty));
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(tAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin();



    }

    private void Slideright(Grid leftpanel)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        DoubleAnimation tAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        tAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3));
        tAnimation.From = 400;
        tAnimation.To = 0;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(tAnimation, leftpanel);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(tAnimation, new PropertyPath(Grid.WidthProperty));
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(tAnimation);
        storyboard.Begin();



    }
```

This all is working fine, however, the animation on change of width is lagging alot, kind of stuttering. Anyway to make it smooth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better idea to animate `RenderTransform`'s parameters instead of complex control size. There is also too many unnecessary grids and stack panels in your code that can slow down your app.

Here's my fix. Translate animations are smooth, because they're handled by GPU. If some animation changes control's size, then CPU must be involved to recalculate new layout on each frame, so it's bad. I have removed this kind of animations and replaced them with simple smooth translations.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="900" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SlideLeftAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="leftpanel"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                             To="-400"
                             Duration="00:00:00.5">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="SlideRightAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="leftpanel"
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                             To="0"
                             Duration="00:00:00.5">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <QuarticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Background>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="PhoneBackgroundBrush"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="OnFlick"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <!-- left panel... keep width as 0 when app starts-->
    <StackPanel Name="leftpanel" Width="400"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-400"/>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <Image 
                Source="/Images/dp.png" 
                Margin="0,40" 
                x:Name="myimage" 
                Tap="myimage_Tap" 
                Height="120" 
                Width="120" 
                Stretch="Fill" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
            <Image.Clip>
                <EllipseGeometry
                            Center="60,60"
                            RadiusX="60"
                            RadiusY="60" />
            </Image.Clip>
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <TextBlock
                Foreground="White"
                Text="name"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,-20,0,0"
                FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
        <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,5">
            <Image Source="/Images/loc.png"
                       Height="30"
                       Width="30"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="20,30,0,0">
            <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                       Height="35"
                       Width="35"/>
            <TextBlock
                Foreground="White"
                Text="text"
                    FontSize="35"
                    Margin="20,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="20,20,0,0"
                Name="x">
            <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                       Height="35"
                       Width="35"/>
            <TextBlock
                Foreground="White"
                Text="text"
                    FontSize="35"
                    Margin="20,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="20,20,0,0">
            <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                       Height="35"
                       Width="35"/>
            <TextBlock
                Foreground="White"
                Text="Moments"
                    FontSize="35"
                    Margin="20,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="20,20,0,0">
            <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                       Height="35"
                       Width="35"/>
            <TextBlock
                Foreground="White"
                Text="text"
                    FontSize="35"
                    Margin="20,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="20,20,0,0">
            <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                       Height="35"
                       Width="35"/>
            <TextBlock
                Foreground="White"
                Text="x"
                    FontSize="35"
                    Margin="20,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="20,20,0,0">
            <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                       Height="35"
                       Width="35"/>
            <TextBlock
                Foreground="White"
                Text="text"
                    FontSize="35"
                    Margin="20,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Line X1="0" X2="1"
                Margin="0,20,0,0"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                Stretch="Fill"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                Height="80">
            <Button 
                    BorderThickness="0" 
                    Width="199"
                    Height="80">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Text="text"
                        Margin="10,0"
                        FontSize="35"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Line X1="0" Y2="100"
                Stroke="White"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                Stretch="Fill"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button BorderThickness="0" 
                    Width="199"
                    Height="80">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Images/x.png"
                           Height="35"
                           Width="35"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="text"
                               Margin="10,0"
                               FontSize="35"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Width="500" x:Name="mainpanel" Background="Black"
      HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
private void OnFlick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            // User flicked towards left ==== show main panel
            if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
            {
                SlideLeftAnimation.Begin();
            }
            // User flicked towards right  ===== show left panel
            else if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
            {
                SlideRightAnimation.Begin();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there is no need to create storyboards in code behind. In my example, they're all in XAML as resources of your main `Grid`.

Note that I have added `TranslateTransform` to your `leftpanel`. It's very important.

```
<StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform X="-400"/>
</StackPanel.RenderTransform>
```

When you set the `X` value to 0, then the panel is visible. But when you set it to -400 it's just moved to the left.

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate control with a lot of content that measured and hurting performance at all animation iterations you should use *CacheMode* setting. That will decrease performance issues.
This might be helpful.

```
CacheMode="BitmapCache"
```

Also you can try to apply different easing functions for your animation, because using them can minimize actual lag. And the final advice is about environment - if this behavior occurs on emulated device try to reproduce it on actual connected device because emulation is never the perfect option.

Tried your xaml. I don't see much lag, but it seems like animation is not quite linear.

My personal advises - try to minimize xaml containers, in some scenarios you use stackPanels with only one child, so they are useless, but all containers invoke measures calculation method for all children while animated. Your xaml filled with duplicating containers for textblock with image - try to create style with new controltemplate, that will be really helpful(but not for the main goal and on that template you can set CacheMode if needed - this is just recommendation). You can extract storyboards from code-behind to xaml so they'll be static without recreation.

```
 <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Hide" x:Name="HideAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.333" From="400" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="animatedGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Open" x:Name="OpenAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.333" From="0" To="400" Storyboard.TargetName="animatedGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

And in your particular case the animation is so simple, that you can avoid measures re-calculating for container elements at all! Just wrap your *leftPanel* in animated grid(my xaml storyBoards already targeted for the *animatedGrid*) So *animatedGrid* wouldn't recalculate measures because it has one child with fixed width.

```
<Grid Name="animatedGrid" Width="400">
        <Grid Name="leftpanel" Width="400"> 
...
```

then your codeBehind transformed into

```
if (animatedGrid.Width > 0){
    HideAnimation.Begin();
}
else{
    OpenAnimation.Begin();
}
```

Comment: didn't help much.. already trying on actual device.. Lumia 920

Comment: can you provide more specific example of Grid content, because I tried to reproduce it, but empty grid or grid with 20 buttons is animated without any performance hit. Also, try to apply cache mode to custom controls if any, specific that ones that contains images or use transparency.